# Store data from an input form into JSON using Dart

Tags: json, dart

I´ve tried the **Avast, Ye Pirates: Write a Web App** from [www.dartlang.org](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/#step-six). So I was thinking about saving the input text into a JSON file. And after I saved it I want to see what I have written into that file. How does this work?

I have this input tag:

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="inputName" maxlength="15">
   </div>
```

And a button:

```
<button id="generateButton" >Enter a name!</button>
```

And the JSON file called 'name.json':

```
 { "names": [ "Anne", "Bette",],
    "appellations": [ "Awesome", "Captain",
    ]}
```

If I enter another name I want to store this into that JSON file. I was thinking about:

Enter another name with the input tag. For example: Betty Meyer.

Then I want to load the file and the output would be:

> Anne Awesome
>
> Bette Captain
>
> Betty Meyer

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file into a data structure, add the values and then generate JSON from the data structure.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

var json = { "names": [ "Anne", "Bette",],
"appellations": [ "Awesome", "Captain",
]};

void main() {
  querySelector('#generateButton').onClick.listen(clickHandler);
}

void clickHandler(e) {
  var file = JSON.encode(json);
  var data = JSON.decode(json);
  data[names].add((querySelector('#inputName') as dom.TextInputElement).value);
  file JSON.encode(data);
  data['names'].forEach(print);
}
```

I omitted the load/save of the file because I don't know what you actually want to do with the JSON and what you mean with 'file' because in the Browser there normally isn't a file.

Comment: I want to store the input text in that json file that's all. And then I want to see what the json file has stored

Comment: What do you mean with 'that json file'.
I think you mean just a variable that holds the JSON values. In this case my example should do what you want.
If you get an error just add a comment and I'll take a look.

Comment: I mean I have a json File called name.json. In this file there is already this: { "names": [ "Anne", "Bette",],
"appellations": [ "Awesome", "Captain",
]}; Now I want to store more Names in it with the input text value.

Comment: You can't read/write from/to files from a web application. In web applications you have to send the JSON to a server and the server saves/loads it to/from a file.

Comment: This is not absolutely true though. You can read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ to learn more.